# Optimize an SQL query to get count of specific answers

Tags: mysql, count

I'm creating a survey with 10 questions. All questions have 5 possible answers with values from 1-5. The data is stored in a database with one row per user. There is a column for the answer to every question.

[image: Data table]

To make bar graphs for the answers to every question, I currently retrieve the count of rows where the value of a specific column is equal to a specific possible answer:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM (`antworten`) WHERE `frage1` = 1
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM (`antworten`) WHERE `frage1` = 2
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM (`antworten`) WHERE `frage1` = 3
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM (`antworten`) WHERE `frage1` = 4
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM (`antworten`) WHERE `frage1` = 5
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM (`antworten`) WHERE `frage2` = 1
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM (`antworten`) WHERE `frage2` = 2
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM (`antworten`) WHERE `frage2` = 3
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM (`antworten`) WHERE `frage2` = 4
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM (`antworten`) WHERE `frage2` = 5
(...)
```

This will generate a graph like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZXCg.png

This is probably very stupid, and there is probably a much better way to retrieve the desired data. I just can't come up with it, could someone help me? :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
SELECT 1 As FrageNummer, frage1 As Frage, count(*) As Anzahl
FROM antworten
GROUP BY frage1
UNION
SELECT 2 As FrageNummer, frage2 As Frage, count(*) As Anzahl
FROM antworten
GROUP BY frage2
```

And so on.

It would of course be easier to query, if the 'fragen' were put into rows instead of columns, i.e. having data like this:

```
id | quartalid | frage_nr | frage
---------------------------------
9  |         5 |        1 |     5
9  |         5 |        2 |     5
9  |         5 |        3 |     2
```

etc.

Then you could query simply like this

```
SELECT frage_nr, frage, count(*)
FROM antworten
GROUP BY frage_nr, frage
```

Comment: Yes I think it will have to go like this +1

Comment: This looks great! Is it also possible to set Anzahl = 0 for every possible answer that returns no result?

Comment: @danilo, that comes for free - count(*) of an empty set *is* equal to 0.

Comment: @Unreason: Yep, but the above query does not list them. But I just realized this is probably a limitation of the table design.

Comment: @danilo, yes I see what you mean now. What you could do is left join the results of the union queries with a query that will contain all possible combinations of questions and question values (this can be a temporary table) and turn the NULL values on missing rows into zeros.

Answer (score 0):

For a single question you can use

```
select  frage1, count(*) as `records_found`
  from  antworten
group by frage1
order by frage1
```

or similar. There's probably a way to do all questions at once using cubes and pivots etc. but I don't know it.

Comment: I don't think you could do that directly (cubes/pivots/crosstabs) since the data is not normalized to start with (repeating groups).